# How to generate PostgreSQL dump from MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, postgresql

Is there any direct method to generate PostgreSQL database dump file from a MySQL database using PHP?

Here I have MySQL database only and no PostgreSQL database, but then I need to deliver data in PostgreSQL file for one of my clients. Is there any direct method without creating a PostgreSQL database?

Thanks

Comment: No, you can't just convert a dump. There are tons of questions on MySQL to PostgreSQL migration, please see the numerous existing answers.

Comment: I have checked some of those and got some solution with a PostgreSQL DB only. So looking for any solution that can read MySQL data and create PostgreSQL file using PHP. Thus I can avoid creating PostgreSQL DB with same data again.

Comment: I doubt there are any.

Comment: Else I may need to create PostgreSQL DB, insert data, generate dump file, then delete those records. Thats my plan B.